# Pygame Import Error: cannot import name _camera while accessing webcamera

Tags: python, pygame

I reinstall pygame 3 times but issue not get resolved. Below is my code.

```
import pygame
import pygame.camera
import time

pygame.init()
pygame.camera.init()

camlist = pygame.camera.list_cameras()
cam = pygame.camera.Camera("C:/Program Files/iBall Face2Face ROBO K20 Webcam/VideoCap",(640,480))
cam.start()
time.sleep(0.1)  # You might need something higher in the beginning
img = cam.get_image()
pygame.image.save(img,"C:/Users/mswatg05/Desktop/filename.jpg")
cam.stop()
```

Answer (score 5):

By default, the camera extension is only enabled on linux builds. Try using a [third party compile](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame), and install [VideoCapture](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#videocapture) from the same place.